# Multiple starts of screen in one program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

When I launch my program from command line, turtle.Terminator error is displayed after first function. I need to launch turtle ten times. This program is module for another program. Do you have any idea how to do this?

I have this code:

```py
from turtle import *


def prvni_chyba():
    pencolor('blue')
    speed(0)
    hideturtle()
    title('Oběšení')
    left(90)
    for i in range(180):
        forward(1)
        left(1)

    left(180)
    penup()
    for i in range(90):
        forward(1)
        right(1)
    bye()


def druha_chyba():
    pencolor('blue')
    speed(0)
    hideturtle()
    title('Oběšení')
    left(90)
    for i in range(180):
        forward(1)
        left(1)

    left(180)
    penup()
    for i in range(90):
        forward(1)
        right(1)

    pendown()
    left(90)
    forward(150)
    sleep(2)
    bye()

prvni_chyba()
druha_chyba()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `bye()`, it's game over for *standalone* turtle.  A working approximation to what you're doing is to use `clearscreen()` instead of `bye()`:

```
from turtle import *
from time import sleep

def prvni_chyba():
    clearscreen()
    hideturtle()
    title('Oběšení blue')
    pencolor('blue')
    speed('fastest')
    setheading(90)

    for _ in range(180):
        forward(1)
        left(1)

    left(180)
    penup()

    for _ in range(90):
        forward(1)
        right(1)

    pendown()

def druha_chyba():
    clearscreen()
    hideturtle()
    title('Oběšení red')
    pencolor('red')
    speed('fastest')
    setheading(90)

    for _ in range(180):
        forward(1)
        left(1)

    left(180)
    penup()

    for _ in range(90):
        forward(1)
        right(1)

    pendown()
    left(90)
    forward(150)

prvni_chyba()
sleep(2)
druha_chyba()
sleep(2)
```

If you need the turtle window to appear, disappear, and appear anew, then you might switch from *standalone* turtle to *embedded* turtle under tkinter.  In that model, you could have tkinter create a window, allocate a turtle canvas, run a function, toss the window, create another window, allocate a turtle canvas and so forth.  Or simply have tkinter hide the window, invoke `clearscreen()` and then make the same window appear again but running a different turtle routine.